# Entities related by many to many not persisted

Tags: symfony

I try to build a form for creating an entity Campaign, in which I can link users. The problem is that when I persist the campaign entity, nothing happens in the jointable.

Here is an extract of the campaign entity :

```
/**
 * Campaign
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="campaign")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CampaignRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Campaign
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="campaigns", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $players;

/**
 * Add players
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $players
 * @return Campaign
 */
public function addPlayer(\AppBundle\Entity\User $players)
{
    $players->addCampaign($this);
    $this->players[] = $players;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove players
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $players
 */
public function removePlayer(\AppBundle\Entity\User $players)
{
    $this->players->removeElement($players);
}

/**
 * Get players
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getPlayers()
{
    return $this->players;
}
}
```

Here is an extract of the User entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User extends \FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Campaign", inversedBy="players", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_campaigns")
 */
protected $campaigns;

/**
 * Add campaign
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Campaign $campaign
 * @return User
 */
public function addCampaign(\AppBundle\Entity\Campaign $campaign)
{
    $campaign->addPlayer($this);
    $this->campaigns[] = $campaign;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove campaign
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Campaign $campaign
 */
public function removeCampaign(\AppBundle\Entity\Campaign $campaign)
{
    $this->campaigns->removeElement($campaign);
}

/**
 * Get campaign
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCampaign()
{
    return $this->campaigns;
}
}
```

Here is my form type :

```
class NewCampaignFormType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
        "label" => 'form.name',
        'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('description','ckeditor',array(
            "label" => 'form.description',
            "required" => true,
        ))
        ->add('players','entity',array(
            'label'=>'form.campaign.players',
            'class'=> 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
            'multiple' => true,
        ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'campaign';
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Campaign',
    ));
}
}
```

And finally, here is my controller :

```
 public function createAction(Request $request){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $campaign = new Campaign();

    $form = $this->createForm(new NewCampaignFormType(),$campaign);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $campaign->setMJ($user->getId());
        $players = $form->get('players');
        var_dump($players);
        $em->persist($campaign);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('show_campaign', array('id'=>$campaign->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('campaign/createCampaign.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'campaign' => $campaign,
    ));
}
```

I am stuck on this for quite a while now, so anyone who has an idea, just try it.

Thank you for reading

Comment: did you checked your entities with `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate`? All is ok? 
Maybe mapping is cached? try `php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`

Comment: I just tried both commands : the validation is OK and the cache is cleared, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You work on `Campain` object which is not owning side of that relation so by default it will not be checked and persisted by Doctrine.

Change sides of relation like here:

Campaign

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="campaigns" , cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_campaigns")
 */
private $players;
```

User

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Campaign", mappedBy="players", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $campaigns;
```

Read more here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts

Comment: This solved my problem, but I still have a question. I tried before to add `foreach($players as $player)
            {
                $campaign->addPlayer($player);
                $em->persist($player);
            }
$em->flush();`
Why did this not saved the entity ?

Comment: Like i said before campaign wasn't owning side of that relation - so doctrine skipped it. if you would add $campaign to User and flush it then it would work.

Comment: I tried to do this as well : 
`$player->addCampaign($campaign)`
but nothing happened.

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for. The link to the documentation isn't working though.